# Automount afp Volume with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, afp, automount

I know this is similar to other open questions about mounting network drives, but this one is slightly different.

I have an AppleScript that runs at startup that looks like this:

```
tell Application "Finder"
  mount volume "afp://192.168.1.105/file_server/user_name
end tell
```

Where `user_name` is specific to the sub folder under `file_server`. On one of my Macs, this works and mounts the sub-folder at `user-name`. On a different mac, it only mounts the `file_server` folder. The one that doesn't mount the full path is OSX 10.9.5. The one that works properly is OSX 10.10.1. Makes me think it's an OSX version difference.

Comment: Assuming that the mount paths are different (in user_name) on both machines, are there any special characters or spaces in the path that fails to work?

Comment: No there are very simple path names. No spaces, no weird characters.

Comment: are there user access/permissions differences

Comment: No, I just verified the permissions. Also, I would think I would get a different error if it was a permissions problem. Currently, the script tries to mount `/file_server/xxx` and I don't get any warning and the `/file_server` fold does mount correctly with the correct permissions. Just not drilled down into `/xxx`

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error/incomplete instructions. Your server URI string is also missing the username. The second line should be:

```
mount volume "afp://your-user-name@192.168.1.105/" as user name "your-user-name"
```